# Preventing iOS devices from sleeping

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, power-management

Is there any straight forward way of preventing an iOS device from sleeping?

The only way I found so far is to open the "Music" app and start playing (and muting the volume if I don't really want to listen to anything), but this feels like a hack, and I'm not sure if it works when the device is running on batteries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, go to:

**Settings > General > Auto-Lock > Never**