# Prevent iOS device from sleeping if plugged to charger

Tags: ios, jailbreak, sleep-wake, charging

This is available in Developer options in Android's system Settings. I'm trying to look for an equivalent in iOS. This is great if I want the screen to be always visible for screen updates/notifications. No problem with battery since it is plugged in anyway.

Is there a Jailbreak tweak for this?

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57371/preventing-ios-devices-from-sleeping) setting applies for both plugged and unplugged. I'm looking for something specific to a plugged device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-Googling, I found this [post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=16993590&postcount=12) on MacRumors. It's not very detailed so I'm going to place the steps to get this working on a jailbroken device:

1. Install SBSettings
2. Go to Activator app
3. Under Anywhere > Power > Connected: set to Switches (Deactivate) > Auto Lock
4. Under Anywhere > Power > Disconnected: set to Switches (Activate) > Auto Lock

This is the first time I used Activator and my goodness, this thing is powerful.

Answer (score 2):

In the past there was an Cydia App called [ScreenDimmer](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.yllier.screendimmer/).

I hope you can find this application via your iPhone and fix your problem.

One of its features:

> - Doesn't dim the screen if the battery is being charged.

Answer (score -1):

Activator means I can customise my phone down to the tiniest detail so it works exactly as I want it to work.