# Prevent non-jailbroken iOS device from sleeping when plugged in to charger

Tags: iphone, ios, sleep-wake

I have a non-jailbroken iPhone running iOS 8.

I'd like to automatically have the device never auto-lock / sleep when it is plugged into power, but auto-lock after a set idle interval when not plugged in.

Is there a way to do this without jailbreaking the device?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119709/prevent-ios-device-from-sleeping-if-plugged-to-charger

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thanks for the link! That question is specifically asking about jailbroken devices, though. I'm interested in a non-jailbreak solution.